# log4j to log4j2 custom RollingPolicy

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j, log4j2

We have a custom rolling policy that is declared in log4j like this:

> log4j.appender.testing.rollingPolicy=com.custom.appender.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
>   log4j.appender.testing.rollingPolicy.timeToRolloverInSeconds=60
>   log4j.appender.testing.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/tmp/cdr.log

How can this be declared in `log4j2.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j2 has a [built-in time based rollover policy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicies) that may do what you want. The below configuration results in a rollover every minute:

```
<Appenders>
  <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
               filePattern="logs/old/app-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}-log.gz">
    <PatternLayout>
      <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </Policies>
  </RollingFile>
```

If you want to create a custom rollover policy, you would need to create a log4j2 plugin that implements [TriggeringPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/TriggeringPolicy.html). A good starting point would be to look at the source code for the built-in [TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html). General information on Log4j custom plugins is [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html).

Comment: Thank you. I figured that the built-in solution works for that case, but thank you for sharing the custom way to do it. I will try it out.